# Flutter ListView/ListTiles are not rendering on the page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter/Dart but I am trying to incorporate a ListView into a project that I am working on but I cannot get it to work. I have tried it at least 12 different ways and it is still not working. I know the issue has something to do with the way I am sizing (or not sizing) the ListView/ListTiles. I have tried adding heights to SizedBoxes, heights to Containers, widths to columns, Expanded, Flexible etc. Nothing has worked. I am not posting the error messages because with all of the solutions I have tried they have all essentially been related to either the height or width of the ListView/ListTile exceeding the limitations of the screen. Below are the latest code snippet I have tried. I know there are several topics on SO that have addressed this but I have not been able to get any of them to work. My ListView should only contain 3 tiles so perhaps a ListView.Builder would be better. I am open to any suggestions or advice. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
class _HotelFormState extends State<HotelForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hotel Form'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TripDates(),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RoomCounts(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**RoomCounts Class**

```
class RoomCounts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 100.0,
        child: new ListView(
          children: new List.generate(3, (i) => new ListTileItem(title: "$i",)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ListTile Class**

```
  class _ListTileItemState extends State<ListTileItem> {

  //Some lists are here

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(widget.icons),
          title: new Text(widget.title),
          trailing: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              _itemCount != 0
                  ? new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: () => setState(() => _itemCount--),)
                  : new Container(),
              new Text(_itemCount.toString()),
              new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () => setState(() => _itemCount++))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You do not need `Scaffold` in `RoomCounts` 
You do not need `Column` in `_ListTileItemState` 
You need `SizedBox` in `trailing` of `ListTile`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HotelForm(),
    );
  }
}

class HotelForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HotelFormState createState() => _HotelFormState();
}

class _HotelFormState extends State<HotelForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hotel Form'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          /*Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TripDates(),
            ],
          ),*/
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RoomCounts(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoomCounts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      child: ListView(
        children: List.generate(
            3,
            (i) => ListTileItem(
                  title: "$i",
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTileItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icons;

  ListTileItem({this.title, this.icons});

  @override
  _ListTileItemState createState() => _ListTileItemState();
}

class _ListTileItemState extends State<ListTileItem> {
  int _itemCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(widget.icons),
      title: Text(widget.title),
      trailing: SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _itemCount != 0
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() => _itemCount--),
                  )
                : Container(),
            Text(_itemCount.toString()),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _itemCount++))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```